# How to hide AngularJS snap menu in only specific pages

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, snap.js

I'm using [snapjs](https://jtrussell.io/angular-snap.js/) to add a nice menu to my mobile web view app but I need to hide(or avoiding drag) the menu in some pages like login or signup. I've tried with `ng-if` and it worked but I have a strange problem. My login/signup page looks like this; [image].
 How do I remove the white space?
My HTML(index.html);

```
  <div class="all-elements">

<sidenav ng-if="isSideDrawerVisible" ></sidenav>
...
...
```

My angular code(app.js);

```
if("/login" === path){
    $scope.isSideDrawerVisible = false;
}else{
    $scope.isSideDrawerVisible = true;
}
```

Note: My console doesn't show any error.

Comment: try with `$rootScope` instead of `$scope`

Comment: Tried but no luck. I also tried to disable drag option of the library with following this link: https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js/#disable-disables-sliding-events but didn't worked that.

Comment: can you update me as to whether my answer worked for you,please read my follow up notes under it aswell.

Comment: didn't work for me(or I couldn't use it properly. I'm new in angular). I can load or unload with `data-snap-ignore='true'` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-hide="$location.path() = urlYouDontWantItToShowIn"`

Comment: yes, the ng-hide will hide whatever tag it is on, the URL would be the parameter

Comment: e.g if the current URL === URL i don't want it to show in, html element will hide